# Is it possible to save DOM manipulations in original HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say some part of my webpage is:

```
<p id = "para"></p>
```

And I perform:

```
 $("#para").text("Hello world!");
```

Now effectively webpage becomes:

```
<p id = "para">Hello world</p>
```

Is there a `JavaScript` or `Jquery` method which can save such DOM manipulations performed in some part of my webpage so that these manipulations reappear when I open my webpage again?

In other words, can I write these changed in my HTML file?

**EDIT: In reality I want to save a form, which will grow larger and larger with everyday use.**

Comment: You can save it in a cookie...

Comment: `localStorage()` is better than cookies for this, but you cannot save the file with changes without server-side code (PHP, ASP.Net etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can use localstorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) to store the changes and you may possibly use mutationobserver (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor changes.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what you are looking for is stock the text to get it later.
I recommand LocalStorage.
Like this :

```
//to stock
localStorage.setItem('myTextVariableName', 'HelloWorld!');

//to load
$("#para").text(localStorage.getItem('myTextVariableName'));
```

Then you'll get it once you load your page another time

Answer (score 0):

plug in js script to html, and code will run every time when you open the html page. Also you can use local storage.

Comment: Merely plugging js to HTML wont help. For example all new rows created by user will get lost. I am yet to read about local storage. Thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: In this case, LocalStorage best solution for you if you can't use server side. Good luck!